# How to sent data to server, remove parameter from url and reload window with new url Javascript, jQuery and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am currently stuck with a problem I can't seem to find a decent solution for.

**Problem**:
I have written some code that will send 2 parameters to an action within a PHP script through a url. I need these parameters sent to the action no matter what. However, after the parameters are sent, I need to remove one of said parameters from the URL and then reload the page with said new URL.

I hope I could give you a clear description of my problem. Following is the code I have written so far.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // Define array with the dashboard id and title as key => value pairs.
  var dashboardArray = <?php echo json_encode(CHtml::listData($dashboards, 'iddashboard', 'title')); ?>;

  // Loop through the elements in the dashboardArray and then create option elements to be added to the above create select element.
  for (var idDashboard in dashboardArray) {
    $('#idDashboards').append($(document.createElement('option')).prop({
      value: idDashboard,
      text: dashboardArray[idDashboard].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + dashboardArray[idDashboard].slice(1)
    }));
  };

  // Get arg01 from the server.
  var arg01 = <?php echo json_encode($arg01); ?>;

  // Prepare URL variable and spike it with arg01 to be sent back to the server.
  var url = 'Path/To/action/Index/index&arg01='+arg01;

  // Button change and function tied to it. Instead of an ajax request, we reload the page completely.
  $("#idDashboards").change(function() {
    // Define dashboardIndex. The -1 stands for the option tag that has already been created.
    var dashboardIndex = $(this).prop('selectedIndex')-1;

    // Sent parameters to actionIndex in Controller and remove dashboardIndex after the request was successful.
    if (url.includes(arg01)) {
      window.location.href = url+"&dashboardIndex="+dashboardIndex;
      console.log("Yes i was here");
    }
    // window.location.href = url;  <---- Here is where the problem begins.
  });
});
```

Comment: This is something the server would do after it receives the request, by issuing a redirect header. Naturally your `// window.location.href = url;  <---- Here is where the problem begins.` line would never be executed, because the previous `window.location.href = url+"&dashboardIndex="+dashboardIndex;` has already caused the browser to leave this page, meaning that all the Javascript within it has been destroyed and is no longer available.

Comment: @ADyson is there a possibility to cache the value somehow and use it again?

Comment: Yes. Exactly how you do it depends on the context, which we don't have. It could be stored on the server (maybe in the session, or other persistent / semi-persistent storage), or in the browser in localstorage or sessionstorage maybe). Depends what/how/where/when you plan to do with it